# Inserting tab between each word in a text file

Tags: python, nlp

I have a utf8 encoded text file `a.txt` containing data in the following form:

```
എടവപ്പാതി\N_NN
തുടങ്ങിയിട്ട്\V_VM_VNF
നാലു\QT_QTC
ദിവസമായി\N_NN
.\RD_PUNC
```

Each line contains only one word, with appropriate tag.

I want to insert a tab between word and tag.

Comment: You should include your question explicitly in the question body and not assume people will infer the question from your title. As it stands your question is a little confusing. Are we to assume that all text after `-->` is the contents of your file?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: On command line: `cut -d'\' -f1,2 a.txt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex can solve the issue for you if you want to use use regex see the python code:

```
import re

regex = r"\\"

test_str = " എടവപ്പാതി\\N_NN തുടങ്ങിയിട്ട്\\V_VM_VNF നാലു\\QT_QTC ദിവസമായി\\N_NN .\\RD_PUNC"

subst = "\\t\\\\"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)
```

> എടവപ്പാതി \N_NN തുടങ്ങിയിട്ട് \V_VM_VNF നാലു  \QT_QTC ദിവസമായി    \N_NN
>   . \RD_PUNC

Answer (score 0):

If word and tag are separated with `\` sign, You can use `replace` function. It would look something like this:

```
for line in open('a.txt').read():
    print(line.replace('\\', '\t')
```

If You want to keep that '\' sign there, You can do this:

```
for line in open('a.txt').read():
    print(line.replace('\\', '\t\\')
```